# Function triggered when click outside an element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, stoppropagation

I want to show the different elements in the loop when I click on body, except from the element `#search-container form`. It works, but only if I first click on the element `#search-container form`, and it only works once.

```
$('html').click(function(event) {
    $('#search-container form').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('html').on('click',function() {
        $('#small-search a').toggleClass('notvisible');
        $('#session').toggleClass('notvisible');
        $('#search-container').css('position','absolute');
        $('#search-container form').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('html').not("#search-container form").on('click',function(){
    $('#small-search a').toggleClass('notvisible');
    $('#session').toggleClass('notvisible');
    $('#search-container').css('position','absolute');
    $('#search-container form').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

Comment: `not()` doesn't work in my code, i did not find out why though, but i already tried with that solution..

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to remove elements from the jQuery object that you are binding the click event to:

```
$('html').not("#search-container form").on('click',function(){
    $('#small-search a').toggleClass('notvisible');
    $('#session').toggleClass('notvisible');
    $('#search-container').css('position','absolute');
    $('#search-container form').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

**Source(s)**

[jQuery API - .not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)